# How can I change the font of a template?

Tags: fonts

I am still a beginner in latex and received a template from my professor. For testing purposes, I would like to change the font to the 'classic' latex font as the one right now is a Helvetica typed font.
The code is down below: I've tried to change some lines but when I did, not only the font changed but the whole template became distorted. Could someone help me out please, thanks!

```
enter code here
% Textsatz, Encodings, etc.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}


% Sans-serif Schriften (Helvetica)
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{cmbright}

% Gemoterie
\usepackage[
    left=2.75cm,
    right=2.75cm,
    top=2.75cm,
    bottom=2.75cm,
    bindingoffset=0.5cm     % <-- Bundsteg
]{geometry}

% Mathematik-Umgebungen und Zeichen
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Grafiken und Farben
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{uibk}{RGB}{0,51,97}

% Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Beschriftungen
\usepackage[
    format=plain, 
    aboveskip=1em,
    belowskip=1em,
    labelfont=bf,
    justification=justified
]{caption}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}

% Fußnoten
\usepackage[
    hang,
    marginal
]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{3pt}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{6pt}

% Zitation
\usepackage{natbib}
```

Comment: Hi there! I'm Tom from the Overleaf support. Note please that I removed the tag [tag:overleaf] as this question is not directly Overleaf-specific. To your question, would commenting out the three lines under `% Sans-serif Schriften (Helvetica)` help?

Comment: Or at least remove `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`.

Answer (score 1):

To focus on only the font commands, the code sample contains several contradictory commands:

- `\usepackage{lmodern}` sets the main font to Latin Modern Roman
- `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` changes the main font to the sans serif family of whatever the main font is (so far, Latin Modern Roman)
- `\usepackage{helvet}` changes the default sans font (`\sfdefault`) to the old Postscript Helvetica font
- `\usepackage{cmbright}` changes the default sans font and the math fonts to Computer Modern Bright and makes this sans-serif font the default

I would recommend you remove *all* of these commands. Then visit the [LaTeX font catalog](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/), choose a font with math support, and use the commands provided on the site to load that font.